# TS2339: Property '*' does not exist on type 'Window'. only in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Win 10 Pro 64 bit

WebStorm: 2018.2.3

Error:

[image]

[image]

in my interfaces.ts file I have:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    dataLayer?: Array<any>;
    gtag?: (...args) => void;
    ga?: (action: string, type: string, data: Object) => void;
  }
}
```

Comment: please try running `tsc` in terminal - can you see the error? Sample project that shows up the issue would be helpful

Comment: likely related to 'cannot find parent tsconfig.json' error. Looks like the issue with tsconfig.json configuration/location

Comment: cannot find parent tsconfig.json looks like is normal to happen for individual files in webstorm, if you look at their tutorials appears all the time, but I don't like it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do:**

```
const eventName = 'event';
const handlerName= doAction;
const target = ( <any>window ); // <===== THIS IS THE WORK AROUND

target.ga && target.ga(eventName, handlerName)
```